# android - Multiple horizontalgridview with title

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-linearlayout, android-tv

I want to create multiple horizontalgridview and each gridview have title above it. I already successfully made and the result is according what I want, but my app becomes so heavy.

My current view is like this:

I have a LinearLayout which contains a textview and a horizontalgridview. let's call it item_layout

I will dynamically add multiple item_layout to a custom LinearLayout (I named it SectionedView) in the main_layout. The code is roughly like this (not my real code):

```
public class SectionedView extends LinearLayout{
    ...
    public void setData(ArrayList<Object> object){
        for(Object o:object){
            View view = ...
            title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.title);
            gridView = (GridView)view.findViewById(R.id.content); 
            title.setText(o.getTitle());
            adapter = new Adapter(o.getItems());
            gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
            addView(view);
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

That custom LinearLayout in the main_layout is located inside a ScrollView.

This is example of the main_layout
[image]

and this one is example of the LinearLayout inside main_layout(basically is the same with previous image).

[image]

My question is does anyone know better workaround for this, how, and why ?
Thanks!

**Edit**:
I am creating an Android TV app so I need to get focus for every item to navigate. but I have tried RecyclerView inside RecyclerView, the inner RecyclerView couldn't get focus :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to create a RecyclerView with a Vertical LayoutManager.
The recyclerView items will be a TextView (the title) and a RecyclerView with an Horizontal LayoutManager.
Inside the horizontal RecyclerView you will put your content.

To allow the items of the RecyclerView to get focus you need put `android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"` in your RecyclerView.

And for the items you may need to add:

```
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:clickable="true"
```

You may have problems with the initial focus, but in that case, you need to set it manually, using `yourView.requestFocus()` in the view that need to start focused.

Then just add a Drawable for the RecyclerView items that indicates if it is focused or not.

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/your_pressed" /> <!-- pressed -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/your_focused" /> <!-- focused -->
<item android:state_hovered="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/your_hovered" /> <!-- hovered -->
<item android:drawable="@drawable/your_default" /> <!-- default --> </selector>
```

Comment: I am using HorizontalGridView (which is a recyclerview too from leanback library) instead of RecyclerView with an Horizontal Layout Manager but basically both of them are the same I think. the "afterdescendants" part is important because items in the inner recyclerview couldn't get focus properly without that! Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Basically your layout looks like Google Play current design.You can achieve this by using Single RecyclerView containing Horizontal RecyclerViews with TextView as Title.

Comment: Hi! I just tried what you said, but the HorizontalGridView inside can't get focus. I forget to mention that I am creating an TV app so I need focus for every item

Comment: what you mean by focus.i dont get it.i not have any idea about tv app.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`TwoWayGridView`](https://github.com/jess-anders/two-way-gridview). It can be used as a drop-in replacement for the normal Android GridView. An Android GridView can be configured to scroll horizontally or vertically.

Attributes:

- **scrollDirectionPortrait (vertical | horizontal)** - The direction the grid will scroll when the device is in portrait orientation
- **scrollDirectionLandscape (vertical | horizontal)** - The direction the grid will scroll when the device is in landscape orientation
- **numRows (integer)** - Number of rows in grid view when in horizontal scrolling mode
- **verticalSpacing (dimension)** - Height of vertical spacing between grid rows
- **rowHeight (dimension)** - Height of each grid row

Here is an example from the demo layout where it is configured to scroll vertically in portrait and horizontally in landscape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.jess.ui.TwoWayGridView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:background="#E8E8E8"
android:id="@+id/gridview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
app:cacheColorHint="#E8E8E8"
app:columnWidth="80dp"
app:rowHeight="80dp"
app:numColumns="auto_fit"
app:numRows="auto_fit"
app:verticalSpacing="16dp"
app:horizontalSpacing="16dp"
app:stretchMode="spacingWidthUniform"
app:scrollDirectionPortrait="vertical"
app:scrollDirectionLandscape="horizontal"
app:gravity="center"/>
```